# angular2 + ionic2 - dynamic [attr.required] seems not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, required

I have a form with a input that is required only if the select.option != 'more'.

I have this, as a test 1==1 for force required.

```
<ion-input id="price" type="number" value="" [ngFormControl]="price"  [attr.required]="1==1"></ion-input>

<ion-select id="type" [ngFormControl]="pricetype">
     <ion-option value="fix">fix</ion-option>
     <ion-option value="more">more</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

When I inspect the input it shows `required=true` or `required=false`, and the input isn't required at all, never. But if I write only `required`, it works...

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently these validators are only properly instantiated when the attributes are added statically like

```
<... required maxlength="5">
```

but not when they are set by Angular bindings.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7393

Comment: so nowadays there is any way to put a value required depending on other inputs option?

Comment: if not, is it possible if the select.option == "more", to set input.value() == "0" ?

Comment: You can set up a form model using `FormBuilder`. This way you can configure validators explicitly.

Comment: could you show me a tutorial or something explaining that? because my problem is with angular2 I don't find a lot of stuff :/

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/FormBuilder-class.html, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihYc9y7dQA0 (especially at 9:30)

Comment: thnk you. all take a look into that